# Java and I need help understanding what code to write out

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am doing a project for class and need help understanding what syntax to write out in IntelliJ
I need the user to be able to type 1, 2, or 3 and to output - Rock for 1, Paper for 2, Scissors for 3.

this is an If, Else, Else if command project and I am struggling to understand this.

Here is what I've got so far

```
public class RockPaperScissors {
    /**
     * Description: The entry point for all java applications
     *
     * @param args - not used in this application
     */




public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Set and create random number generator
    Random random = new Random();

    //Assign and create local variables
    Scanner consoleIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int computerGuess = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
    int userGuess = 0;
    String input;
    String output;

    System.out.println(createCoolHeader());


    //Get input from the user, User decides to choose Rock, Paper or Scissors
    System.out.print("Select Rock, Paper or Scissors: ");
    input = cin.nextLine();
```

Comment: _..I am struggling to understand this..._ What is "this" exactly?

Comment: Arey you struggling to write the logic?

Comment: If you are having trouble with the `if`, `elseif`, `else` statements (or the `switch` and `case` statements, you can take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).

Comment: Yes still having troubles

Comment: Trying to break it down to just plain english so I understand it, thats the problem :(

Comment: @JavaNoob87 This is how they work in plain english:  IF something is true, DO this block of code, ELSE do this OTHER block of code.  In other words, when the `if` is true, `else` will NOT be used.  `else` will ALWAYS be used when `if` is false.  This does not explain `else if` which I suggest you look up to see how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the input:

1. if check the input is equal to "1", then print "Rock".
2. else if check the input is equal to "2", then print "Paper".
3. else if check the input is equal to "3", then print "Scissors".
4. else, then print "invalid input".

The pseudo code for the above steps is below:

if computer input is int, declare input as int and  use input == 1, meaning compare input value with == for 1,2 and 3 instead of input.equals("1") or "2" and "3".

or if you want to convert int to String, use this Integer.toString(int value); where this method converts int value to String.

```
if(input.equals("1"))
{
    System.out.println("Rock");
}
else if(input.equals("2"))
{
    //print paper
}
else if(input.equals("3"))
{
    //print Scissors
}
else
{
    //invalid input
}
```

Comment: Note that he is using `int` for the computer guess too, so he would either need to convert that to a `String`, or take `input` as an `int`.

Comment: Thank you @Nexevis for the inputs and i modified the answer as per that.

Comment: So if I want the user to type 1 for rock, 2 for paper or 3 for scissors, thats the syntax I would use?

Comment: • Create a “cool” welcome header (see output above)
• Create an appropriate class header comment
• Create an appropriate main method header comment
• Use a Scanner object to get all input into a String
• Use Java Random class to create the computer guess (random number)
• The data type for the computer guess and the user guess are both integers
• Convert input into an integer
• Use a try/catch construct to handle the “NumberFormatException” when converting from the String input to an integer.
• Use pseudo-code throughout your java code

Comment: • Use if/else if/else constructs for the algorithm to find a winner of the game
• Check for value entered to be between 1 and 3 inclusive
• Check for value entered to be an integer only
• Use a String called output for all console output (I will explain this in class)
• Make sure and close any open resources (Scanner object)
• All output should be tabbed over one tab space except winner, and error messages
• Align the output for the winner on the colon (see my output above)
• Error messages should be tabbed two tab spaces

Comment: Thats what i am assigned to do. Struggling with understanding where everything goes in IntelliJ. My "cool header" outputs just fine. The option of stating "Select 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors:" out puts just fine. No errors found. But i still need to be able to type in any of those options then the pc to output a option and then to determine who won or lost and if i type in something other than 1, 2 or 3 a error is found and it says game over.